# Hibernate - Crash with 2 @OneToMany

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Hibernate crashes when using more than one @OneToMany entries in my Users.entity and I don't understand why.

I have a table for users (primary key userID) and various other tables which refer to the primary key userID by a foreign key set in database (InnoDB set and foreign key is set in each depending table).

Here an example with three tables:

Table users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (`userID` int(11) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`userID`);
```

Table: vacationrequests

```
CREATE TABLE `vacationrequests` (`requestID` int(11) NOT NULL,`userID` int(4) NOT NULL,) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ALTER TABLE `vacationrequests` ADD CONSTRAINT `userID` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE; COMMIT;
```

Table monthend:

```
CREATE TABLE `monthend` (`monthendID` int(11) NOT NULL,`userID` int(4) NOT NULL,) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Entity Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")

public class Users {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="userID")
private int userID;

... .... (other variables)

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="monthend")
private Set<Monthend> monthend;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="vacationrequests")
private Set<Vacationrequests> vacationrequests;

public Users() {

}
```

Entity Vacationrequests:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="vacationrequests")

public class Vacationrequests {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="requestID")
private int requestID;

... .... (other variables)

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="userID", nullable = false)
private Users users;

public Vacationrequests() {

}
```

Entity Monthend:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="monthend")

public class Monthend {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="monthendID")
private int monthendID;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="userID", nullable = false)
private Users users;

@Column(name="clientID")
private int clientID;

@Column(name="month")
private int month;

@Column(name="year")
private int year;

@Column(name="monthend")
private int monthend;

public Monthend() {

}
```

Working Query:

```
List<Object> listJoinUsersMonthend = session.createQuery("from Monthend m inner join m.users as users where m.clientID = :clientID AND m.year = :year AND users.loginclass = 0 AND users.isactive = 1 AND m.monthend = 0 AND m.month < :month order by users.userID asc")
                        .setInteger("clientID", user.getClientID())
                        .setInteger("year", year)
                        .setInteger("month", month)
                        .getResultList();
```

This second query i would like to integrate:

```
List<Object> listJoinVacationrequestsUsers = session.createQuery("from Vacationrequests v inner join v.users as users where v.clientID = :clientID AND v.approved=0 AND v.vacationtype=1 AND YEAR(v.startdate) = :year" )
                        .setInteger("clientID", user.getClientID())
                        .setInteger("year", year)
                        .getResultList();
```

Everything works fine with just one query and one entry in the Users.entity. As soon as I add the two entries hibernate just crashes and there is no error message. Is it not possible to do two @OneToMany statements in a entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the mapping of the associations in the Users entity.
You should change the **mappedBy** attribute of the associations to specify the field name that references the current entity in the associated one (in this case **users**), like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
private Set<Monthend> monthend;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
private Set<Vacationrequests> vacationrequests;
```